# Disable auth0 remember me meteor

Tags: meteor, logout, auth0

I have used auth0 with meteor js and dont want to use remember me feature of auth0. I want to disable it . I have tried with

https://demo.auth0.com/v2/logout?returnTo=http://localhost:3000

it works but it gives white screen in mobile for a second.

any other options for it.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, are you using Lock, the login dialogue? If so, you can set the rememberLastLogin attribute to false on initialization, documented here:

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/customization#rememberlastlogin-boolean-

Comment: not able to use lock in meteor js. Auth0 not fully supported for meteor js.